# Optimum Fermentation Temperature

Tags: fermentation, yeast, fermentation-temperature, wheat-beer

I am planning on brewing a wheat beer with Danstar Munich Wheat Beer Dry Yeast. I didn't realize until I had already made the purchase that the optimum temperature for fermentation was 55-65. I don't currently have the equipment to maintain that temperature and was hoping to keep it around 70-73.

What ill effects, if any, will this have on the beer?

Should I just bite the bullet and buy a different yeast strain?

Comment: It will probably be more estery -- more banana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style guidelines for wheat beers mention ester notes as being common in German, and moderate in American wheat beers. I expect you might be ok. On the other hand, you might go with a saison or other farmhouse style that's more heat tolerant. You'll get more predictable results staying within the recommended temperature.

Comment: is it true that if I am over the optimum temperature for fermentation it will always develop higher ester notes?

Comment: I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that it is true that you will always develop _more_ estery smell and taste, but that it will not be a linear relationship. Different strains of yeast will develop ester notes at different rates, just like they have different heat tolerances. I would also expect these to be related, but that may not be true.